# Bootstrap mixed grid layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to define a layout which looks like this on large displays:

```
.----------------------------.
|       |        B           |
|  A    |____________________|
|       |                    |
|       |                    |
|       |                    |
|       |        C           |
|       |                    |
|_______|____________________|
```

"A" should be fixed width, while "B" and "C" should dynamically expand to fully cover the remaining available width (i.e. should not be maximized and leave an empty margin on large displays - I think this is the fluid layout).

Now, upon decreasing the screen width below a specific amount, I would like to these 3 blocks rearranged to be under each other in the order of A, B, C, with all 3 utilizing the full available width.

Can you help me with this please? So far I have the following setup:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-2">A</div>
    <div class="col-md-10">B</div>
    <div class="col-md-10">C</div>
</div>
```

This looks fine in full width, but when decreasing the width, it starts to shrink also "A" in width which I do not want.

If I add a fixed width to "A", it collapses B & C under A too early when decreasing the width - I would like B & C to decrease dynamically, unlike A - I think specifying a width messes up fully the layout.

Here is a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/pucigobujaco/1/edit).

Comment: making working demo would be easier to help you

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili http://www.bootply.com/t48KfpUw7H Now you can help him....

Comment: @TheLittlePig No need for Bootply when we have [code snippets](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?cb=1) now!

Comment: @DavidG So edit the Bootstrap tag info and delete the tools... I don't want to loose time in including all the JS and Css when bootply is already ready for bootstrap....

Comment: @TheLittlePig Delete what tools? You confused me! I do think there should be an 'include Bootstrap' function to code snippets though.

Comment: @DavidG Don't worry : http://stackoverflow.com/tags/twitter-bootstrap/info paragraph 'Tools to test bootstrap code'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Here is something :*

### In collaboration with [@Christina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1004312/christina)

*(see comments)*

Exemple with fixed column at `200px` and `min-width 600px` :

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/olRbQrHoWQ

**HTML** :

```
<div class="aside">
A
</div>
<div class="main">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 b">B</div>  
       </div>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 c">C</div>  
       </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**CSS** :

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px){
   html, body{
      height:100%; 
   }
  .aside{
    height:100%;
    width:200px;
    float:left;
  }
  .main{   
      z-index: -1;
      position:absolute;
      background:cyan;
      width:100%;
      padding-left: 200px;
      float:left;
      height:100%;
    }

}
```

---

**Updated** : *`position:absolute` is not usefull, and `margin-left` on `.aside` is better*

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/7Y9t8B1oAY

**CSS**:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) { 
    html,
    body {
        height: 100%
    }
    .aside {
        height: 100%;
        width: 200px;
        float: left;
        margin-right: -200px;
    }
    .main {
        background: cyan;
        width: 100%;
        padding-left: 200px;
        float: left;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
        z-index: -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, exactly what I would have done...box-sizing:border-box makes this nice and simple

Comment: You don't need position:absolute though.

Comment: @Christina Can I update my answer in appending your comments for a better read ?

Comment: I don't see your answer anymore, but yes you can

Comment: Oh, this is your answer. Hard to tell sometimes.

Comment: Margin right on the aside is negative the width      margin-right: -200px;

Comment: @Christina Lol that's true, I'll wait for futur info, maybe asker has found a better solution. Thanks a lot ^^

Comment: This is the best answer ;-).

Answer (score 2):

Your Bootstrap code is slightly wrong as you are missing the `row` class. But if you nest B and C on different rows inside the `col-md-10`, it works. I've added background colours to emphasise the blocks.

```css
.A { background-color: red; }
.B { background-color: blue; }
.C { background-color: green; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 A">
      A
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="B">B</div>
        <div class="C">C</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But how do I make A to be fixed width if B and C are next to A? It is now dynamically changing when the screen is resized.

It should be 100% width if B and C are collapsed under A, but that is fine.

Comment: Then you don't want it do be fluid, I've changed the answer.

Comment: I do want B and C to be fluid, as said above. A should be fixed width, B and C should use up all the remaining screen space. When decreasing the screen width, B and C should squeeze horizontally and then collapse under A, upon which A, B and C should equally take up the full screen width (if easier, A can remain the same fixed width).

Comment: Then you can "abuse" Bootstrap and force the first column to be fixed width, but that's a bit nasty.

Comment: And that's what I wrote above that I tried, but it's not working properly, because it messes up the resizing of the fluid columns.

Comment: An alternative is to take your sidebar out of the Bootstrap container, that may work. But the fluid container uses percent which makes it awkward.

Answer (score -2):

Something like this ?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-2">A</div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="col-md-10-sub">B</div>
        <div class="col-md-10-sub">C</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container-fluid {
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    left: 5%;
}
.col-md-2 {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
}
.col-md-10 {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:100px;
    width: auto;
    height: 200px;
}
.col-md-10-sub {
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    height: auto;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2Lybysk1/)

Comment: It's not recommended to change the Bootstrap styles too much, it can have major effects across a site.